# Linux Mint: ALERT! "UUID" does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

Tags: linux-mint, dual-boot, busybox, chrome-os

I am trying to duel boot Linux Mint with ChromeOS from an SD card. I installed it from a bootable usb and when I run it from the SD card, it stays on the boot up screen for a few minutes, then this happens:

```
[        1.148939] cros_ec_lpcs GOOG0004:00: IRQ index 0 not found
[        1.227155] genirq: Flags mismatch irq 0. 0000080 (i801_smbus) vs 00015a00
(timer)
[        1.227155] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.1: Failed to allocate irq 0: -16
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
-  Boot argos (cat /proc/cmdline)
        -  Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
-  Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! UUID=247d6725-7cdc-407f-bc9f-42ae6aba6bb2 does not exist. Droppint to a shell!


BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.3) built-in shell (ash)
Enter ‘help’ for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) [  3115.015452] elants_i2c i2c-ELAN0001:00: unknown packet ff ff ff ff

(initramfs)
```

I have tried to find as much information as I can regarding the issue and none of the solutions worked.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I don't have an actual solution, but what I do have is a hypothesis: I think that means your SD card is "disappearing"/losing power/otherwise shutting off. Couple things off the top of my head that can cause that: USB/PCI power management (dunno if you can turn that off in the BIOS of a Chromebook, but if you can, you might want to try; perhaps there are kernel parameters you could change if you can't do it via the BIOS?), driver issues (could try a bleeding edge distro or an older version of Mint to see if it gives the same issue), or a dodgy SD card.

Comment: I'll probably try a different SD card and if that doesn't work, an older version of mint. Thanks!

Comment: Ok so I just tried using GalliumOS instead of Mint and it worked. I think it's because Gallium is made to run on Chromebooks.